# How could I upload an interactive Rmarkdown file to Kaggle?

Tags: r, r-markdown, data-visualization, kaggle

The file I saved from RSTudio is a Rmarkdown file but with an HTML option.  It looks like I cannot save the encoding.  I tried to choose 'Save with encoding' and 'Save All' but with no improvements.  Can anyone advise?

Also, I tried to launch the Rmarkdown file on Kaggle, but it seemed while saving, the notebook feedback from Kaggle failed.  Back to RStudio, I already made sure it is saved as a Rmarkdown file.  Whilst so, the file can bestill viewed by text but to no avail for the coding, as understood.

I wonder if it needs to save as 'Shiny' instead of the 'HTML' option.
But Shiny seems rather complicated to use as I am a beginner.

Can anyone advise what to do to show the data visualization/graphs merely?  If not the interactive one?

Answer (score 0):

**I finally succeed knit** the Rmarkdown file to rmd.html/pdf/docx with graphs (ggplot)fine.  **But still I HAVE NOT YET MANAGED TO LAUNCH THE GRAPHICS ON KAGGLE,** THOUGH SCRIPS RUNS SUCCESSFUL.  SO I AM STILL ASKING FOR SOLUTIONS...SOS>>>>>

**For succeeding to knit th eRmarkdown, .RMD to html:**
I kept trial and error as the error messages look similar towards different issues as seems.  Most common are error on parse ( text = code,...), 'characters missing',  or error on chunks options.
In brief, those are related to the need to quote
sufficient libraries,
state clearly the location and source, format of data files
and remembering each time new dataset is launched, the source file has to be {r} again.

```
rm(list = ls())

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, results='hide')
```

```
 library(readxl)
 my data 1 <- read_excel(".xlsx", range = ":", na = "NA")


library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
```

```
 library(readxl)
 my data 2 <- read_excel(".xlsx", range = ":", na = "NA")


library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
```

Though a bit clumsy, this is how I found work so far after trying many other solutions, if you find better code and work, please feel free revert.  Appreciate.